# Display uiactionsheet from tab bar item in uitabbarcontroller

Tags: iphone, action, tabbar

In one of my apps, I want to display an action sheet from a tab bar item in a tabbar controller and this action sheet should be accessible through out anywhere, if I click that tab bar item. I afraid this can be done, as the tab bar is tightly coupled with its view controllers. If anyone has any work around, it will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

UIActionSheet has a method called showFromTabbar:

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a parentView controller of TabBarController and present actionSheet from that viewController. Basically that View Controller holds nothing except tabBarController itself.

Comment: Your idea seems striking, but would you mind posting some example code, that would be really helpful.

Comment: @manoj sorry buddy but I cannot create a sample right now. You will have to do it yourself otherwise you will not learn much. Try it yourself then ask if you stuck. First try it yourself before you ask question.

Answer (score 0):

Use,

```
[myActionSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
```

in the view controller which is inside a tab bar controller.

Comment: but where should I call this method?

Comment: I guess, you have to have a centralize class which should own and init the tab bar controller, if you want to share the action sheet for all the tab bars. Rahul points out similar thing. Otherwise, you can call this method when you need to show it, in your view controller of the corresponding tab bar.